# how to use repl to create instance of a case class defined in object

Tags: scala, loading, read-eval-print-loop

I have a problem in creating the instance of the case class after loading the methods in Scala repl.

here is the code.

```
object Game {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val player1 = new Player("monu", 344)
        val player2 = new Player("pankaj", 78)
        declareWinner(player1, player2)
    }

    def printWinner(p: Player): Unit =
        println(p.name + " is the winner!")

    def declareWinner(p1: Player, p2: Player): Unit =
        if (p1.score > p2.score) printWinner(p1)
        else printWinner(p2)

case class Player(name: String, score: Int)
}
```

**Output:**

```
scala> :paste Game.scala
Pasting file Game.scala...
defined object Game

scala> val bob = Player("Bob",8 )
<console>:7: error: not found: value Player
       val bob = Player("Bob",8 )
```

but there is no problem if i remove the object definiton and just keep methods in the code as:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val player1 = new Player("monu", 344)
        val player2 = new Player("pankaj", 78)
        declareWinner(player1, player2)
    }

    def printWinner(p: Player): Unit =
        println(p.name + " is the winner!")

    def declareWinner(p1: Player, p2: Player): Unit =
        if (p1.score > p2.score) printWinner(p1)
        else printWinner(p2)

case class Player(name: String, score: Int)
```

**Output:**

```
scala> :paste Game.scala
Pasting file Game.scala...
main: (args: Array[String])Unit
printWinner: (p: Player)Unit
declareWinner: (p1: Player, p2: Player)Unit
defined class Player

scala> val bob = Player("Bob",8 )
bob: Player = Player(Bob,8)
```

It will be really helpful if somebody can suggest a method to fix the issue with the first case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way to fix the issue is accessing the `Player` case class using `Game.Player` as:
`val bob = Game.Player("Bob",8 )`.

The second way is to import the class first, using `import Game._` or `import Game.Player` and then executing your code as it was before `val bob = Player("Bob",8 )`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you need to use `Game.Player` instead of just `Player`, since it's `Game`'s inner class.